# Gnome terminal misbehave - command typing in one row only

Tags: command-line

like i said in the title, my terminal behaving strangely for past few months.
I made a screenshot/ video capture  so you can see what I'm talking about:

https://youtu.be/2lw_hwdejWE

Many thanks!

Comment: Does generating a new default profile fix the problem? (Terminal title bar menu, Preferences, Profile+)

Comment: update your question with the output of `declare -p PS1`

Comment: No , I added the profile and it remains the same. But I solved it, tnx.

Answer (score 1):

You customized your `$PS1` in `.bashrc` (or profiles) and broke it ;-)
Add some brackets `[ ]` for each one of your characters.

You can find more here : https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/191004/419015